# REST queuing / proxy server software

Tags: php, rest, service, web

We've been discussing how to implement a 2-way rest service we're setting up for a website and it quickly became apparent that without some kind of queuing system we'd be in trouble if the connection between the two points was unavailable.

As the budget is fairly tight on this project I started to wonder if there was already something out there that could take an incoming request and forward it on to the remote end and act as though it wasn't there yet queue up the requests if the remote end wasn't available or was slow, and return a 'queued' response if that was the case.

I did a google but couldn't find anything obvious or simple.. perhaps this isn't the right thing to do?

Any advise much appreciated!!

Thanks,
John

Comment: Platform is linux, but would appreciate a cross platform proxy as client side is windows.

Comment: What you're asking for seems to be a reverse-proxy, but I'm not sure there exists a http reverse-proxy with intermediate state cache, especially taking into account that it should be suitable for general purpose REST, and not for a specific service. So I think you should implement all quality assuring logic at the client (trap timeouts, resend requests on error, etc).